# Sneak damage modifier stacking

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

- Sneak attacks do 6x damage with one-handed weapons
- Sneak attacks with daggers do 15x damage (end perk on skill tree)

A dagger is a one handed weapon, so does this mean either;

1. Daggers just deal *15x damage*
2. Daggers deal (15x + 6x) *21x damage*
3. Daggers are op and deal (15x * 6x) *90x damage*

Comment: I'd certainly interpret that as option 1, anything else would probably be overpowered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the text of the perk itself:

> Sneak attacks with daggers do 15x damage

The perk is concise and to the point: Daggers do 15x damage. Not, "increased by 15%" or the like, just, "do 15x damage".

This holds up in game, where Daggers do 2.5 times the sneak attack damage of other one-handed weapons.